# How to deselect selected fixedcolumn datatable in jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, datatables

I have a table that can be selected using `onclick event` on specific cell, also can use `checkbox` to select random rows or select all. Then, I also have `fixed column header` both vertical and the first horizontal column.

The problem is when I select a row and delete the content for the cells inserted using a button, it will empty the cells, remove the data from the database and the remove the selected class **BUT** it will not remove the `fixedcolumn` selected class and `checkbox` class. So how to fix this?

**Here's my DataTable code:**

```
var table1 = $('#table1').DataTable(
{                    
   pageLength : 500,      
   lengthChange: false,
   deferRender: true,
   scrollY:  800,
   scrollCollapse: true,
   scrollX: true,
   bSort: false,
   cache: true,
   autoWidth: false,                    
   columnDefs: [
      {
         targets: 0,                            
         checkboxes: 
         {
            selectRow: true
         }
      }
   ],
   select: {
      style: 'multi',
      selector: 'td:not(:nth-child(3), :nth-child(4), :nth-child(5), :nth-child(8), :nth-child(9), :nth-child(12), :nth-child(13), :nth-child(14), :nth-child(15), :nth-child(16), :nth-child(17), :nth-child(18), :nth-child(19), :nth-child(20), :nth-child(21), :nth-child(22), :nth-child(23), :nth-child(24))'
   },
   fixedColumns:   {
      leftColumns: 2
   }
});
```

**Here's my jquery code :**

```
$('.btnN2').click(function(){
   var answer = confirm('Delete N2 : Are you sure you want to delete selected items?');
   if (answer)
   {
      console.log('yes');
      var rows = $(table1.rows({selected: true}).$('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function()
      {
         return $(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-getstockcode') : null;
      }));

      var getstockcodes = [];

      $.each(rows, function(index, rowId) 
      {
         console.log(rowId) 
         getstockcodes.push(rowId);
      });

      $.ajax({
         url: 'del_n2',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {"getstockcodes": JSON.stringify(getstockcodes)},
         dataType: 'JSON',
         success:function(data){                                 
            console.log(data);
            $(table1.rows({selected: true}).$('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function()
            {
                if($(this).prop("checked"))
                {
                   $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find(".note2").val('');
                   $(this).prop("checked", false);
                   table1.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
                   table1.fixedColumns().update();
                   console.log('reset');
                }  
            }));
         }
      });
    }
    else
    {
       console.log('cancel');
    }
 });
```

**Here's before I click the delete button :**

[image: Before]

**Here's after I click the delete button :**

[image: After]

**Here's Gyrocode.com solution :**
[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

#### CAUSE

FixedColumns extension creates a separate table to create effect of a fixed column. This table is not accessible by `$()` DataTables API methods.

#### SOLUTION

Use [`fixedColumns().update()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/fixedColumns().update()) API method after you finished manipulating the main table to update the data shown in the FixedColumns.

```
table1.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
table1.fixedColumns().update();
```

#### DEMO

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/4tq8bws0/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I have updated my post. It works but the `select-all checkbox` still `checked`. I manage to remove that but it still `checked` without the tick icon.